# Does Magento support Oauth 2.0?

Tags: magento, oauth

I've been working on a Magento project that needs to interact with a mobile app. The product owner wants us to use the Magento REST API OAuth authentication. The app is built in html5 by another company, so they need to use JavaScript to send their POST/GET/DELETE/PUT calls. The other company can't seem to get this to work. Because we have a joint deadline I decided to put some time into this problem. I did some research and OAuth 1.0 is just not so compatible with JavaScript. OAuth 2.0 is... But I can't really find anything about Magento and OAuth 2.0.

Does Magento support Oauth 2.0 out of the box like it supports OAuth 1.0?

I think not, but I want to be sure...

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current API supports OAuth 1.0a.

But you can have customizations as used here
[Clean Magento Google Api OAuth2 Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593056/clean-magento-google-api-oauth2-integration)